# How do I blur a YUV videoframe with Agora SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, agora.io

I'm using the following method from the [Advanced Video Example](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Video/blob/master/iOS%26macOS/Agora-Plugin-Raw-Data-API-Objective-C/Agora-Plugin-Raw-Data-API-iOS-Objective-C/VideoChatViewController.m) on Github to capture the raw video data:

```
- (AgoraVideoRawData *)mediaDataPlugin:(AgoraMediaDataPlugin *)mediaDataPlugin didCapturedVideoRawData:(AgoraVideoRawData *)videoRawData
```

I have already been able to convert the Y U V buffers to a `CVPixelBuffer` > `CIImage` and apply the blur, but i'm having trouble translating the `CIImage` data back into YUV buffers.

I already succeeded into setting random values to the yuv-buffers which results in a grey video frame being sent to the other user.

```
memset(videoRawData.yBuffer, 128, videoRawData.yStride * videoRawData.height);
memset(videoRawData.uBuffer, 128, videoRawData.uStride * videoRawData.height / 2);
memset(videoRawData.vBuffer, 128, videoRawData.vStride * videoRawData.height / 2);
```

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to translate CIImage data back into YUV buffers? Or if there is a more efficient way to blur a YUV videodata stream, i'm willing to try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solutation that works for me. I will try to post a complete answer so others might find a solution that works for them. See comments in code for more explanation.

Set these helpers somewhere in your file. This will be used later to calculate the RGB values of each color pixel:

```
#define Mask8(x) ( (x) & 0xFF )
#define R(x) ( Mask8(x) )
#define G(x) ( Mask8(x >> 8 ) )
#define B(x) ( Mask8(x >> 16) )
```

All code posted here is inside the `- (AgoraVideoRawData *)mediaDataPlugin:(AgoraMediaDataPlugin *)mediaDataPlugin didCapturedVideoRawData:(AgoraVideoRawData *)videoRawData` method for simplicity sake of answerring this question.

```
- (AgoraVideoRawData *)mediaDataPlugin:(AgoraMediaDataPlugin *)mediaDataPlugin didCapturedVideoRawData:(AgoraVideoRawData *)videoRawData
{
    // create pixelbuffer from raw video data
    NSDictionary *pixelAttributes = @{(NSString *)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey:@{}};
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
    CVReturn result = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          videoRawData.width,
                                          videoRawData.height,
                                          kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange,   //  NV12
                                          (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(pixelAttributes),
                                          &pixelBuffer);
    if (result != kCVReturnSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to create cvpixelbuffer %d", result);
    }
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
    unsigned char *yDestPlane = (unsigned char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < videoRawData.height; i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < videoRawData.width; j ++) {
            yDestPlane[k++] = videoRawData.yBuffer[j + i * videoRawData.yStride];
        }
    }
    unsigned char *uvDestPlane = (unsigned char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1);
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < videoRawData.height / 2; i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < videoRawData.width / 2; j ++) {
            uvDestPlane[k++] = videoRawData.uBuffer[j + i * videoRawData.uStride];
            uvDestPlane[k++] = videoRawData.vBuffer[j + i * videoRawData.vStride];
        }
    }
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

    // create CIImage from pixel buffer
    CIImage *coreImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];

    // apply pixel filter to image
    CIFilter *pixelFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPixellate"];
    [pixelFilter setDefaults];
    [pixelFilter setValue:coreImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [pixelFilter setValue:@40 forKey:@"inputScale"];
    CIVector *vector = [[CIVector alloc] initWithX:160 Y:160]; // x & y should be multiple of 'inputScale' parameter
    [pixelFilter setValue:vector forKey:@"inputCenter"];
    CIImage *outputBlurredImage = [pixelFilter outputImage];

    CIContext *blurImageContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef inputCGImage = [blurImageContext createCGImage:outputBlurredImage fromRect:[coreImage extent]];

    // write blurred image data to YUV buffers
    NSUInteger blurredWidth = CGImageGetWidth(inputCGImage);
    NSUInteger blurredHeight = CGImageGetHeight(inputCGImage);

    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * blurredWidth;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    UInt32 * pixels = (UInt32 *) calloc(blurredHeight * blurredWidth, sizeof(UInt32));

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, blurredWidth, blurredHeight, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, blurredWidth, blurredHeight), inputCGImage);

    int frameSize = videoRawData.width * videoRawData.height;
    int yIndex = 0; // Y start index
    int uIndex = frameSize; // U statt index
    int vIndex = frameSize * 5 / 4; // V start index: w*h*5/4

    // allocate buffers to store YUV data
    UInt32 *currentPixel = pixels;
    char *yBuffer = malloc( sizeof(char) * ( frameSize + 1 ) );
    char *uBuffer = malloc( sizeof(char) * ( uIndex + frameSize + 1 ) );
    char *vBuffer = malloc( sizeof(char) * ( vIndex + frameSize + 1 ) );

    // loop through each RGB pixel and translate to YUV
    for (int j = 0; j < blurredHeight; j++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < blurredWidth; i++) {
          UInt32 color = *currentPixel;
          UInt32 R = R(color);
          UInt32 G = G(color);
          UInt32 B = B(color);

          UInt32 Y = ((66 * R + 129 * G + 25 * B + 128) >> 8) + 16;
          UInt32 U = ((-38 * R - 74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
          UInt32 V = ((112 * R - 94 * G - 18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;

          yBuffer[yIndex++] = Y;
          if (j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0) {
              uBuffer[uIndex++] = U;
              vBuffer[vIndex++] = V;
          }

        currentPixel++;
      }
    }

    // copy new YUV values to given videoRawData object buffers
    memcpy((void*)videoRawData.yBuffer, yBuffer, strlen(yBuffer));
    memcpy((void*)videoRawData.uBuffer, uBuffer, strlen(uBuffer));
    memcpy((void*)videoRawData.vBuffer, vBuffer, strlen(vBuffer));

    // cleanup
    CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);
    CGImageRelease(inputCGImage);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    free(pixels);
    free(yBuffer);
    free(uBuffer);
    free(vBuffer);

    return videoRawData;
}
```